# Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug'. Error after upgrading to Android Studio 3.2.1

Tags: android-studio

I got the error after making the project:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug'.

  > Parameter 'directory' is not a directory

This started after upgrading to Android Studio 3.2.1

Any ideas what this could be?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The following command worked for me.

```
./gradlew assembleDebug --rerun-tasks
```

Comment: Run the command from your project's directory. There should be a file called "gradlew". If you are using Windows, the file is "gradlew.bat".

Comment: command retun BUILD FAILED but problem solved Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you get this error when using databinding its base reason is same id at one layout xml file. Can you check views ids.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error at build time and it was caused by a binding variable (that declared inside `<data></data>` with a Java reserved word as name. For instance `<variable name="case" type="com.mydomain.Case" />`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i found this in the App gradle.

```
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}
```

I just commented it out and all work fine.
this binding option is generated when i was added a ScrollActivity to my project and deleted the next time