# app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug fails from Android Studio and succeeds with gradlew

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

I have a fresh installation of Android Studio on Windows and I open an existing app project. After it completes the syncing, I run the Build > Make Project and the `app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug` task fails with the `[TAG] Failed to resolve variable` errors:

[image: app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebugapp:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug]

But, if I follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57700844) to similar question and run `gradlew.bat` in command line inside the project folder:

```
gradlew.bat assembleDebug --rerun-tasks
```

this command succeeds.

Then, if I go back to the Android Studio, then Build > Make Project succeeds there too.

Unfortunately, [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57700844) to that similar question does not clarify any of these:

- Why do I need to run `gradlew` manually?
- Why Android Studio does not
  run any equivalent of the `gradlew`?
- What Android Studio or project
  configuration is missing?

Comment: I suspect the issues were due to different versions of Gradle used by Android Studio vs the versioned deployed by the Gradle wrapper (`gradlew`).